# implement the "exact" filter option in Kendo UI AutoComplete

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, autocomplete, overriding, exact-match

Is there a way to override/add the "exact" filter option for the Kendo UI AutoComplete. (Currently there are only three options for the filter field, "startswith", "contains", and "endswith".) For the "exact" filter option, all data items which have the exact same data with the current widget value will be displayed in the suggestion popup.

The code snippet is bellow:

$("#someInputId").kendoAutoComplete({ 
           minLength: 1,  
           dataTextField: "lastName",  
           dataSource: data,  
           filter: "exact",  
           placeholder: "Enter here...",  
           separator: ", "  
});

If the user enters the word which is EXACT match the lastName field of data set, all the correspondent data items will be pop out.

Thanks a lot of your helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "exact" filter, use "equals" and it should work. Be carefull to letters cases.

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/iJafa